# Nokia Exchang Ad Events doesn't fired in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

when i used Nokia Exchange Add SDk i tried to work with add events when it fired and i found that in documentation :

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InneractiveAd.AdClicked += new 
            InneractiveAd.IaAdClicked(InneractiveAd_AdClicked);
        }

void InneractiveAd_AdClicked(object sender)
{
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InneractiveAd: AdClicked");
}
```

when i click the add nothing happen and in debuging the no entrance for this method which mean that event didn't fire.

so is there any mistakes in this code ? or there is another way to do that?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Currently waiting a response from support.

Comment: i sent for them but i didn't get response from days , please if you get the solution tell me , thanks PutraKg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new version inneractiveAdSDK-Nokia-WP8-v1.1.2 for Windows Phone 8 recently released. Update your SDK and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   InneractiveAd.AdClicked += InneractiveAd_AdClicked;
}

void InneractiveAd_AdClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InneractiveAd: AdClicked");
}
```

Comment: when i tried this code i got this complie error :No overload for 'InneractiveAd_AdClicked' matches delegate 'Inneractive.Ad.InneractiveAd.IaAdClicked'

Comment: Hmm. I'm really not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved in v1.1.2  as mentioned in release notes :

inneractiveAdSDK-Nokia-WP8-v1.1.2
- Release date: 1/29/2013
- Supports WP 8.0
- Add optional parameters for ad sizes supports. Banner's Required/Optional parameters are  only relevant for C#.
- Additional Ad alignment optional parameters.
**- Events are no longer static.
- Events bug was resolved.**
- Validation handling was added.
- Improve the refresh ad handling.
- Performance was improved.